What test would give me a qualitative recognition of the presence of benzene in methylphenidate?
I need a couple of tests to recognize the presence of benzene in my compound (methyphenidate).
I've looked into tests with bromide or Freidel-Crafts reactions but I'm not sure if both or neither would give a positive result with the specific compound I'm working with.
Could you help me understand if they would work or suggest any other test which could?

Have you tried NMR ?

NMR+LCMS? When you do a reaction and you can see with your bare eye that something happens, that does not prove yet, that it was indeed your starting material that you assume.

Trace benzene would best be detected, measured, by GC or GC-ir or GC-MS. Raman might work for ppm levels. A careful headspace analysis should work.

Arey to looking fo a test that show whether pure methylphenidate contains an aromatic ring or a test that shows there is free benzene in a sample of methylphenidate?

With my experience in Natural Products Chemistry, I think NMR is superior to any other method to identify a organic compound. And if you are a graduate student in any university you may get access to use a reliable NMR spectrometer to identify your compound, methylphenidate. Following is the reference spectrum of in methylphenidate hydrochloride this site:

The aromatic region is clear without any other interfering peaks so that the presence of aromatic ring can be easily confirmed. Further, Ref.1 has shown NMR spectra of some derivatives of methylphenidate, aromatic ring of which can also be clear. For example, stacked 1H-NMR spectra of erythro-, and threo-2-methoxymethylphenidate with their 1:1 mixture are shown below:


References:

Howard M. Deutsch, Qing Shi, Ewa Gruszecka-Kowalik, and Margaret M. Schweri, "Synthesis and Pharmacology of Potential Cocaine Antagonists. 2. Structure−Activity Relationship Studies of Aromatic Ring-Substituted Methylphenidate Analogs," J. Med. Chem. 1996, 39(6), 1201–1209 (https://doi.org/10.1021/jm950697c).

